# how can I move the hg workbench console to the side?

Tags: user-interface, tortoisehg

Update at Feb 7 2015:

Now, in tortoisehg-3.3.0, dockable/detachable console window is back. So this question no longer exists.

======================================================================

Hi，I run into a problem when I am using hg wordbench.After I update the tortoisehg to tortoisehg-3.2.0-x64， the console will be at bottom rather than at side.

This is the screenshot.

[image]

In the previous version of hg the console was automatically at right side, so I didn't know how to set the location.But now tortoisehg-3.2.0 changed it.

My OS version is windows 7 SP1 64bit. With latest update.

Excuse me for my poor English and expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. In pre-3.2 THG, log pane was independent peer entity of Workbench (movable, detachable) at the level of Repository Registry.

Now it just one additional **View Type** with hardcoded position, you can only change dimensions

Comment: I reported this problem as a bug on the thortoisehg bitbucket repo. https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/3984/bring-back-the-dockable-detachable-console